# List passed inside method and populated with values appears empty in the outer scope

Tags: java, oop

I got this code

```
private void updateTrackPositionForImages(ImageService imageService, String documentId, LambdaLogger logger, List<EnhancedSpeechmark> speechmarks) {
        List<ImageDetail> imagesByDocumentId = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            imageService.getImagesByDocumentId(documentId, imagesByDocumentId, logger);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log("difficult exception: " + e.getMessage());
            logger.log("stack trace");
            logger.log(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        logger.log("after get query");
        logger.log(imagesByDocumentId.toString());

        updateImageTrackPosition(speechmarks, imagesByDocumentId, logger);
        logger.log("out of updateImageTrackPosition");
        imageService.saveOrUpdateImageRecords(documentId, imagesByDocumentId, logger);
    }



    public void getImagesByDocumentId(String documentId, List<ImageDetail> imagesByDocumentId, LambdaLogger logger) {
        if (documentId == null || documentId.trim().isEmpty()) {
            logger.log("DocumentId is null or empty");
            return; // Or throw an exception as per your error handling policy
        }

        try {
            // Configure the query with the partition key condition
            QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional
                    .keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(documentId).build());

            logger.log("Querying for DocumentId: " + documentId);

            // Perform the query using the enhanced client
            imagesTable.query(queryConditional).stream()
                    .forEach(page -> imagesByDocumentId.addAll(page.items()));
            logger.log("Query successful. Items found: " + imagesByDocumentId.size());

            logger.log(imagesByDocumentId.toString());
        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            logger.log("Error retrieving images for documentId " + documentId + ": " + e.getMessage());
            // Log additional details from the exception if needed
        }
    }
```

This

```
logger.log(imagesByDocumentId.toString());
```

from inside getImagesByDocumentId() prints

```
[ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=0, url='null', name='null', width=1920.0, height=938.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=1, url='null', name='null', width=1256.0, height=483.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=2, url='null', name='null', width=333.0, height=133.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=3, url='null', name='null', width=1104.0, height=830.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=4, url='null', name='null', width=1600.0, height=965.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=5, url='null', name='null', width=1266.0, height=362.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=6, url='null', name='null', width=1443.0, height=890.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=7, url='null', name='null', width=1833.0, height=1077.0}, ImageDetail{documentId='2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2', id='null', trackPosition=8, url='null', name='null', width=1443.0, height=890.0}]
```

And inside updateTrackPositionForImages(), it prints nothing. Why? I would think that since its being passed by reference the value should be updated to the outer scope too. No?

Comment: in 'updateTrackPositionForImages' you are creating a local List with name imagesByDocumentId , so it doesn't use the same as the other method

Comment: but the other method is called from inside updateTrackPositionForImages()

Comment: you don't return the List you generate in that method, do you?

Comment: but I pass it as a reference - when I was returning it I'd get npe for some reason

Comment: No, you don't. Java doesn't do "pass by reference". Java applies "pass by value".

Comment: The statement "Java doesn't do 'pass by reference'" is correct in the sense that Java passes object references by value. This means that Java passes a copy of the reference to the object, not the actual object itself. However, since the copy of the reference still refers to the original object, changes made to the object through this reference are reflected in the original object

Comment: are these methods in the same class/service/component?

Comment: they are different class, and in different packages

Comment: if that second method is actually a service call, what is possible is that you have problems with asynchronous vs synchronous execution. your code in your original method doesn't wait until the service/method call is completed, before continuingµ

Comment: Can you share the whole classes? Given this I cannot see any reason for it not to work..

Comment: Side note: `e.getStackTrace()` returns an array, so logging `e.getStackTrace().toString()` will not be very useful. Usually, loggers have methods accepting an exception.